# Highstock not displaying stock chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a weird problem - My highstock JS is not displaying the graph. It displays all other components. I am just trying out their example app but because of CORS issues I am rendering the JSON locally.

When I hard code the data and run the same code in JSFiddle, the data is displayed fine.

My code:

```
var chart1;
$.getJSON("http://localhost:5000/stock", function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    chart1 = Highcharts.stockChart('stockDiv', {
        xAxis: {
            min: Date.UTC(2013, 6, 17, 16, 00), //previous day  at 16.00
            max: new Date().getTime() //get actual time
        },
        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            turboThreshold: data.length,
        }]
    });
});
```

My HTML

```
<div class="container content">
    <div id="stockDiv" class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

I am loading this js in a local python webserver and rendering the json data at the /stock url.

I checked in the debugger to see that the data is indeed present.
Totally flumoxxed by why this data is not getting displayed.
Appreciate any help !

This is what my output looks like 
[image]

Comment: Do you have any Highcharts errors in the console? It is really difficult to tell what's wrong with it when the chart is rendered correctly with hardcoded data. Try to update the chart data when chart load event occurs and check if it will be plotted correctly.

Comment: Nope, no errors in the console. I even hard coded the data value within the getJSON call - no luck so far. I'll keep debugging.